# How do I make an image pin in google maps center align with the location rather than bottom align in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am making an android app and I have an image marker (a circle). When it is on the map, the bottom of the circle aligns with the location, rather than the center of the circle. How would I fix this?

```
mMap!!.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(location!!.latitude, location!!.longitude)).title("Me").snippet("My Location").icon(
                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.circle)
                )
            )
```

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739526/centering-bitmap-marker-google-maps-android-api-v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate with this parameter:

```
.anchor(x, y)
```

Example usage:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                    .anchor(0.5f, 1.0f)
                    .title("title")
                    .snippet("snippet"));
```

Comment: It should be .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f) for center but thank you